# Ruby on Rails: Populate dropdown with two fields of database record

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, search, drop-down-menu

In my database I have a Users table that looks something like:

```
 User_ID    Firstname    Surname    Company
 1          Steve        Jobs       Apple
 2          Bill         Gates      Microsoft
```

What I am trying to do is make a drop down menu in a form that would allow a user to choose from selecting their name or their company, e.g. when Steve Jobs is logged in he can either select "Steve" or "Apple" in the drop down menu.

What I have tried so far is the following:

```
<%= f.select :from_name, [session[:user_id],session[:user_id]] %>
```

Which obviously didn't work because it only returns the user id of the logged in user.

```
<%= f.select :from_name, [@user.firstname,@user.company] %>
```

Which gave me the error `undefined method`firstname for nil:NilClass`

My Users controller is as follows:

```
class UsersController < ApplicationController
before_filter :check_authorization, :except => [:show, :new, :create, :search ]

  def index
    @users = User.all
  end

  def show
    @user = User.find(params[:id])
  end

  def new
    @user = User.new
  end

  def edit
    @user = User.find(params[:id])
  end

  def create
    @user = User.new(user_params)
    @user.role = "customer"
    if @user.save       
        session[:user_id] = @user.id
        # Save a copy of the email address entered by the user into the Accounts table
        @account = Account.create(email: params[:user][:primaryemailaddress], user_id: session[:user_id])
        redirect_to root_path
    else
        render 'new'
    end
  end

  def update
    @user = User.find(params[:id])

    if @user.update(user_params)
        redirect_to @user
    else
        render 'edit'
    end
  end

  def destroy
    @user = User.find(params[:id])
    @user.destroy
    redirect_to users_path
  end

  private

  def user_params
    params.require(:user).permit(:title, :firstname, :surname, :housenumber, :street, :city, :postcode, :company, :primaryemailaddress, :password)
  end  
end
```

And my _form.html.erb is:

```
<%= form_for(@email) do |f| %>
  <% if @email.errors.any? %>
    <div id="error_explanation">
      <h2><%= pluralize(@email.errors.count, "error") %> prohibited this email from being saved:</h2>

      <ul>
      <% @email.errors.full_messages.each do |message| %>
        <li><%= message %></li>
      <% end %>
      </ul>
    </div>
  <% end %>

  <p>
    <%= f.label :from_name %><br>
    <%= f.select :from_name, [current_user.firstname, current_user.company] %>
  </p>

  <p>
    <%= f.label :From_Email_Address %><br>
    <%= f.collection_select :account_id, Account.where(user_id: session[:user_id]), 
      :id,:email %>
  </p>

  <p>
    <%= f.label :to %><br>
    <%= f.text_field :to %>
  </p>

  <p>
    <%= f.label :cc %><br>
    <%= f.text_field :cc %>
  </p>

  <p>
    <%= f.label :bcc %><br>
    <%= f.text_field :bcc %>
  </p>

  <p>
    <%= f.label :subject %><br>
    <%= f.text_field :subject %>
  </p>

  <p>
    <%= f.label :message %><br>
    <%= f.text_field :message %>
  </p>

  <div class="actions">
    <%= f.submit %>
  </div>
<% end %>
```

I'm not too sure how to solve this issue, can someone please help.

Comment: Did you defined @user from controller's action ?

Comment: Apologies, I do not know, I have just added my controller

Comment: why don't you use current_user instaed of @user

Comment: first find @user then access it's. if user not found then how to fetch username and company.

Comment: How do I find @user Chaudhary Prakash

Comment: add one condition @user.present? then after check . i think its working

Comment: Ok, I have done this `<% if @user.present? %><%= f.select :from_name, [@user.firstname, @user.company] %><% end %>` and the drop down does not display - so the user is not present, how can I fix this?

Comment: I have just added the line: `<% @user = User.where(id: session[:user_id]) %>` before the `<% if @user.present? %>` and this passes the if statement (so the @user is now present) but I still can't get it to display the firstname or company

Comment: @BenSmith I guess you are accessing `EmailsController`. And on that controller's new or edit method there is no `@user` variable.

Comment: please remove before filter except method then check  only add before_filter :check_authorization

Comment: @Emu I have just added in `@user = session[:user_id]` into the new and edit methods in the `EmailsController` and I am now getting the error `undefined method 'firstname' for 2:Fixnum`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@BenSmith I guess you are accessing `EmailsController`. And on that controller's new or edit method there is no `@user` variable.

In your edit and new method add

`@user = User.find(session[:user_id])`

Answer (score 0):

> undefined method firstname for nil:NilClass

Seems like some how `@user` is `nil`

create a helper and check for presence of `@user`

```
<%= f.select :from_name, dropdown_values %>
```

**application_helper.rb**

```
def dropdown_values
  if @user.present?
    [@user.firstname, @user.company]
  else
    ['default', 'values']
  end
end
```

Comment: Hi Deepak, that returned the error `undefined local variable or method current_user for #<#<Class:0x3f57f90>:0x804baf0>`

Comment: can you please post the view of the action which you are using

Comment: and the action name

Comment: What do you mean the view of the action? Do you mean the _form.html.erb?

Comment: what are the default values you want when the user is not present

Comment: The user should always be present because they can only get to this form if logged in

Comment: I have just added that and still get the error `undefined method firstname for #<User::ActiveRecord_Relation:0x844f6b0>`

Answer (score 0):

```
<p>
    <%= f.label :from_name %><br>
    <%= f.select :from_name, [current_user.firstname, current_user.company] if @user.present?%>
  </p>
```

because User.new time create blank object doesn't find username.i hope its will be help you.